# Erro no URLloader - flex

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-flex

Estou criando uma aplicação em flex (AS3), onde preciso obter informações de uma url externa. Porém ao utilizar o URLloader ocorre o erro:

> "Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation:"

---

## Meu código:

```
sUrlListas = "https://www.us8.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/members.json?apikey=XXXXX&id=XXX; 
urlLoader2 = new URLLoader();

urlLoader2.load(new URLRequest(sUrlListas));
```

## Meu crossdomain:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="*"/>    
</cross-domain-policy>
```

## Crossdomain deles:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

---

Rodo essa aplicação em localhost. Já li muito sobre o problema ser do crossdomain, porém não me parece ser exatamente este problema.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se as configurações globais do **Flash Player** está como *Sempre permitir* para que o arquivo local possa acessar URLs externas. Você pode verificar [clicando aqui](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Adicione o valor `Security.allowDomain("*")` no começo da sua classe `Main`. Se ainda não der certo, teste também com `Security.allowInsecureDomain("*")`. Acesse [este link](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html) para ter mais informações sobre esta classe.

Pode ser que seu Flash não esteja carregando o arquivo *crossdomain.xml* (O que é difícil, mas não impossível). Adicione também o valor `Security.loadPolicyFile("url_do_seu_crossdomain.xml")`.

Retire o `www` da sua URL e teste.

Se mesmo assim ainda não funcionar, se possível, coloque o seu arquivo SWF no mesmo domínio da requisição.

Essas são algumas formas de resolver este problema, faça uma coisa de cada vez para verificar o que realmente é.